# Splitting a string in json using python

Tags: python, json, string, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a simple Json file

input.json

```
[
{
    "title": "Person",
    "type": "object",
    "required": "firstName",
    "min_max": "200/600"
},
{
    "title": "Person1",
    "type": "object2",
    "required": "firstName1",
    "min_max": "230/630"
},
{
    "title": "Person2",
    "type": "object2",
    "required": "firstName2",
    "min_max": "201/601"
},
{
    "title": "Person3",
    "type": "object3",
    "required": "firstName3",
    "min_max": "2000/6000"
},
{
    "title": "Person4",
    "type": "object4",
    "required": "firstName4",
    "min_max": "null"
},
{
    "title": "Person4",
    "type": "object4",
    "required": "firstName4",
    "min_max": "1024 / 256"
},

{
    "title": "Person4",
    "type": "object4",
    "required": "firstName4",
    "min_max": "0"
}

]
```

I am trying to create a new json file with new data. I would like to split  "min_max" into two different fields ie., min and max. Below is the code written in python.

```
import json
input=open('input.json', 'r')
output=open('test.json', 'w')
json_decode=json.load(input)

result = []
for item in json_decode:
    my_dict={}
    my_dict['title']=item.get('title')
    my_dict['min']=item.get('min_max')
    my_dict['max']=item.get('min_max')
    result.append(my_dict)

data=json.dumps(result, output)
output.write(data)
output.close()
```

How do I split the string into two different values. Also, is there any possibility of printing the json output in order.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON file seems to be written wrong (the example one).  It is not a list.  It is just a single associated array (or dictionary, in Python). Additionally, you don't seem to be using `json.dumps` properly.  It only takes 1 argument.  I also figured it would be easier to just create the dictionary inline.  And you don't seem to be splitting the min_max properly.

Here's the correct input:

```
[{
    "title": "Person",
    "type": "object",
    "required": "firstName",
    "min_max": "20/60"
}]
```

Here's your new code:

```
import json

with open('input.json', 'r') as inp, open('test.json', 'w') as outp:
    json_decode=json.load(inp)    
    result = []
    for temp in json_decode:
        minMax = temp["min_max"].split("/")
        result.append({
            "title":temp["title"],
            "min":minMax[0],
            "max":minMax[1]
        })    
    data=json.dumps(result)
    outp.write(data)
```

Comment: Thank you @neil. It is showing "IndexError: list index out of range". I believe this is because my json file is too big. How can i overcome this?

Comment: @neil - I just edited the json data in my question. It is just an instance of data. I have more and more similar data.

Comment: You would have to put commas in between each one.  I don't know how the data looks without looking at it.

Comment: @neil - what commas you are reffering to?. Also, I don't have any specific data. Just imagine the same data with more and more dictionaries. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have a `min_max` value that doesn't have a `/` in it, which is causing it to run into trouble when attempting to reference the values in the `minMax` array from the `.split('/')` call.  You will need to check to make sure that `len(minMax) == 2` before attempting to add it to the result - and if it is not, add in code that does what you want to do in that case.

Comment: @scwagher - I just edited the json file. yes, you are right. some min_max has value '0', some has 'null' and some has space in front and after '/'. I think you will get a clear idea after seeing the edited json file. How should I over come this? Thank you.

Comment: change `min` to `minMax[0] if len(minMax) == 2 else 0` and max to tha tbut change index to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import json 

nl=[]
for di in json.loads(js):
    min_,sep,max_=map(lambda s: s.strip(), di['min_max'].partition('/'))
    if sep=='/':
        del di['min_max']
        di['min']=min_
        di['max']=max_
    nl.append(di)

print json.dumps(nl)
```

This keeps the `"min_max"` values that cannot be separated into two values unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Table + Python == Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# Read old json to a dataframe
df = pd.read_json("input.json")

# Create two new columns based on min_max
# Removes empty spaces with strip()
# Returns [None,None] if length of split is not equal to 2
df['min'], df['max'] = (zip(*df['min_max'].apply
                        (lambda x: [i.strip() for i in x.split("/")] 
                         if len(x.split("/"))== 2 else [None,None])))

# 'delete' (drop) min_max column
df.drop('min_max', axis=1, inplace=True)

# output to json again
df.to_json("test.json",orient='records')
```

Result:

```
[{'max': '600',
 'min': '200',
  'required': 'firstName',
  'title': 'Person',
  'type': 'object'},
 {'max': '630',
  'min': '230',
  'required': 'firstName1',
  'title': 'Person1',
  'type': 'object2'},
 {'max': '601',
  'min': '201',
  'required': 'firstName2',
  'title': 'Person2',
  'type': 'object2'},
 {'max': '6000',
  'min': '2000',
  'required': 'firstName3',
  'title': 'Person3',
  'type': 'object3'},
 {'max': None,
  'min': None,
 ...
```